# Why is Apache reading .htaccess files even though they are disabled?

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

According to Apache documentation, setting the `AllowOverride` and `AllowOverrideList` options to `None`, will completely ignore `.htaccess` files. Not even attempt to read them from the filesystem.

I have both of those options set to `none` but Apache still reads the `.htaccess` files.  I know this because if I put a `.htaccess` file in with some valid directives it throws a 500 error.  Commenting out the directives (essentially an empty `.htaccess` file) the 500 error is not thrown.  So obviously Apache is still reading the `.htaccess` files.

> Apache2 error log (sanitized for public consumption):
> [Thu Jul 30 23:36:35.393831 2020] [core:alert] [pid 60903] [client d.d.d.d:10554] /var/www/example/.htaccess: Require not allowed here, referer: `http://example.net/`

The question is why?  What am I missing?  How to make it behave according to the documentation? i.e. not even attempt to read the `.htaccess` files.

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

> When this directive is set to None and AllowOverrideList is set to
> None, .htaccess files are completely ignored. In this case, the server
> will not even attempt to read .htaccess files in the filesystem.

Comment: What does the Apache2 error log show when it throws the 500 error?

Comment: Showing the config file might be useful.

Comment: Apache2 error log shows  
Sanitized for public consumption...  

[Thu Jul 30 23:36:35.393831 2020] [core:alert] [pid 60903] [client d.d.d.d:10554] /var/www/example/.htaccess: Require not allowed here, referer: http://example.net/

Comment: What version of Apache 2.4 are you using?

Comment: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) built: Apr 2 2020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would appear to be a bug in earlier versions of Apache 2.4 that was reportedly fixed in Apache 2.4.20
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58528

The bug would seem to be that when explicitly setting `AllowOverrideList None` the value is not being correctly *reset*.

I have verified that I see the same (incorrect) behaviour in Apache 2.4.7

If you have never set `AllowOverrideList` elsewhere in your server config then you can omit this directive, since the *default* is `None`. (When left as *default* it does appear to be correctly interpreted as per the docs.)

Comment: Thanks so much MrWhite.  This indeed is the problem.  Now there is no more .htaccess access.  :)